# Get non zero indices from Mat OpenCV

Tags: vector, opencv, indexing, find

I have a binary Matrix and would like to get the indices of the non-zero elements, preferably as a vector of cv::Points. There is a function that counts non zero elements, but that's not what I need.

In Matlab, the equivalent call would be simply *find*().

I could search through the entire matrix and save the indices, but that is not classy!

Comment: opencv is rarely classy.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using `numpy` module see [NumPy For Matlab Users](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html). There is `nonzero` function which is eqivalent to matlab `find`.

```
>>> m = cv.CreateMat(2,2,cv.CV_16SC1)
>>> a = numpy.asarray(m)
>>> a.nonzero()
(array([1, 1]), array([0, 1]))
```

Comment: It's Python. May be I should delete the answer. Ok, use python or downvote my answer

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with numpy (quite classy), but I am already invested in C++. I would upvote your answer, but I am not reputable enough!

Comment: this should probably be the accepted answer considering that its currently the only "classy" way to do it.